# Nightwatch.js testing Chrome Extension Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, nightwatch.js

While testing a chrome extension with Nightwatch.js I came over an issue where I am not able to test or use the *content script* of the extension. This is because my testing environment opens the *popup files* and the *options files* within its browser (Chrome Driver) - therefore there is no space/place for the content script to load in.

I know think about ways how to run the *content script* properly so the extension can use its functions.

**Nightwatch test:**

```
'[popup page] - "should switch page to saved system settings"': function (browser) {
    browser
      .click('#change')
      .pause()
      .assert.title('Google', "check if right page popped up")
  },
```

**is triggering following (popup.js):**

```
  //popup.button.wechseln == "#change"
  $(popup.button.wechseln).on('click', events.changeUrlEventHandler);
```

**and finally (content.js)**

```
 if (request.action == "changeUrl") {
      changeUrl(projectInfo, request);
    }
```

I do need to have the *content-script* available anyhow. Since the manifest is injecting it into the page...how can I explicitly running the *content script* before my test runs?

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding your question, but have you tried adding it in the before function in your base-test-class (on the prototype)?

Comment: hm sounds like an idea